# Java FX multiple scenes crash

Tags: javafx, controller, scene

My first scene works normal but when I try to use second scene it crashes. I guess i'm doing something wrong? Says something like I neeed to set Root, but tried a lot of diffrent things none worked,kept crashing

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("visual.fxml"));
        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
        ctrl = loader.getController();
        primaryStage.setTitle("World of Snopscraft");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1024, 768));
        primaryStage.show();
        ctrl.setPrevStage(primaryStage);
}
```

Controller:

```
boolean canSetCard=false;
int selectedCard;

Game game;
Stage primaryStage;

@FXML
public void initialize() {

    game=new Game(this);
    game.start();
};

public void setScene() throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("end.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1024, 768));
    primaryStage.show();

}

public void setPrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
}

public void playCard1(){
    try {
        setScene();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //if(game.getCanPlay()==true)game.play(0);

}
```

Edit: Added error code and controller
Error:

```
Javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root hasn't been set. Use method setRoot() before load.
/C:/Users/Rene/IdeaProjects/snops/out/production/snops/sample/end.fxml:11
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear. You need to provide full code of controller class and also the full error log.

Comment: I edited post, this play button is just to try it out, I want to implement it later into diffrent code, but can't get it working

Comment: If you use the `<fx:root>` tag as root element of the fxml you need to call `FXMLLoader.setRoot` on the instance of the `FXMLLoader` you use to load the fxml before calling the `load` method. You're not doing this since you do not even create a `FXMLLoader` instance but use one of the static `load` methods...